# ValueError: make_sure failure: Opset 11 is required for half_pixel_centers=True for node model/up_sampling2d_1/resize/ResizeNearestNeighbor

Tags: machine-learning, onnx, enet, tf2onnx

I want my `Keras` model to be converted to `ONNX opset 10`, but the error keeps showing up.
What do I do?

I tried changing the interpolation to *bilinear* but it still threw me an error. I also tried to use the resize function and I got this error:

> ValueError: make_sure failure: Opset 11 is required for
> half_pixel_centers=True for node
> model/tf.image.resize_4/resize/ResizeNearestNeighbor